# How can I start a service on a remote machine using a different user?

Tags: windows, services

I have the same service running on a dozen test machines. Said service has croaked (specifically, it was shut down and disabled by a test, and the test died halfway through), and I want to re-enable and restart it on all of those machines. The normal solution is `sc \\machine config ServiceName start=auto` followed by `sc \\machine start ServiceName`, and it works fine if my user account is authorized on the other machine. But since these are cloned test machines created from a common image that doesn't know me from Adam, they don't recognize me. I know I could go in and authorize myself on those machines, but they get wiped on a fairly regular basis and I'm trying to save some time.

I know the local Administrator password for all of these machines. (And it's the same thing, due to the cloning.) How can I run `sc.exe` so that it will log in with that user? Or is there another way I can enable and start those services programatically from my machine? (I have a dead-simple looping PowerShell script all ready to go, but it's not much use if I can't find a command to run that will be accepted.)

For reference, here's the error message I'm getting:

```
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sc \\machine config ServiceName start= auto obj= Username password= PWD

Answer (score 3):

Use [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542), which works just like sc.exe but it enables you to logon to a remote system using a different account. Go [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897542) to download it. Usage is `psservice [\\computer [-u username] [-p password]] <command> <options>` using the same commands as sc.exe. So given your example, you would enter

```
psservice \\machine -u AdminUserName -p AdminPassword config ServiceName start=auto
```

and then

```
psservice \\machine -u AdminUserName -p AdminPassword start ServiceName
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to give some actual instructions? That would make this answer more helpful to other visitors with the same problem.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Done.